# Drink database design

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to design a drink database and need some help with the design.

I created the following tables: an ingredients table that lists all possible ingredients (i.e. rum, coke, vodka and orange juice). A drinks table with a list of all possible drinks (i.e. "rum & coke", "screwdriver"). Finally a Recipes tables describes how to make the drink, so for "rum & coke" there are two entires one with the ingredients ID for rum and one for ingredients ID for coke both with a foreign key to the same drink id.

What I want to do is given a list of available ingredients id - 1(rum), 2(coke) and 3(vodka) I want to come up with a list of drinks that are possible to make. So I can make rum & coke but not a screw driver because I don't have orange juice.

Any suggestions on how to write such a select statement or how to better design the tables?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have your 3 tables: `Drinks`, `Ingredients` and `Recipes`, here's a Select statement which would give you only `Drinks` which their `Recipes` have *all* of your given `Ingredients`:

```
Select
    d.*
From
    Drinks d
Where
    not exists
    (
        select 1 
        from Recipes r 
        where r.DrinkId = d.Id and r.IngredientId in (1,2,3)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT coktail_id,count(ingredient_id) as nb_ingredient
FROM coktail_ingredient
WHERE ingredient_id IN (1,2,3) --where 1 is rhum , 2 is vodka and 3 is coke
group by coktail_id
)
where  nb_ingredient = 3--3 for the number of ingredient you need
```

Is the technique I use.